# Pandas dataframe: search and assign unique values to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) with following values

```
a b c d
1 2 3 0
1 7 9 0
1 3 6 0
2 4 5 1
2 8 2 1
3 4 5 0
3 8 2 0
```

I need to create a new dataframe from the above one with following values

```
a  d
1  0
2  1
3  0
```

that is, I need to get the values that is unique by column 'a'. 'a' and 'd' values are always same. For example, in above when 'a' = 1, 'd' is either 0/1 but can not be both. Similarly, when 'a' = 2, 'd' is 0/1 and can not be both.

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add the code here so we can help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *subset* columns *a* and *d* and then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df[['a','d']].drop_duplicates()

#   a   d
#0  1   0
#3  2   1
#5  3   0
```